# Malfunction, unkown reason

Tags: c

I have to examine passwords. The password is strong, when it contains uppercases, lowercases, digits and at least 8 characters. I wrote this C program, but it always displays "weak password". I don't know the reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 50

int strenght(char word[],int length)
{
    int sup = 0;
    int low = 0;
    int dig = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(word[i]) == 1)
            sup++;

        else if(islower(word[i]) == 1)
            low++;

        else if(isdigit(word[i]) == 1)
            dig++;
    }
    if(sup > 0 && low > 0 && dig > 0 && length >= 8)
        return 1;
        else
        return 0;
}
int main()
{
    printf("Type the password until '*'\n");

    char word[N];

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Password: ");
        fgets(word, N, stdin);
        int length = strlen(word) - 1;
        if(word[0] == '*')
            break;
        else
        {
            if(strenght(word, length) == 1)
                printf("Strong password\n");
            if(strenght(word, length) == 0)
                printf("Weak password\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about `if(isupper(word[i])  == word[i]) sup++;` and the same for the rest.

Comment: @DavidRanieri - he is avoiding the `'\n'` from `fgets()` but he should check that `strlen(word) > 0` to avoid a negative index.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yeah ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing the results of the `isupper`, `islower` and `isdigit` calls to `1`. Don't do this! Each of these functions will return **zero** if the condition *is not* satisfied and ***any non-zero value*** if it *is* satisfied. (see [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isupper/)).

So, in place of:

```c
    if(isupper(word[i]) == 1)
        sup++;
```

just do this:

```c
    if(isupper(word[i]))
        sup++;
```

or, if you want to keep the explicit nature of the comparison, use:

```c
    if(isupper(word[i]) != 0)
        sup++;
```

(And similarly for the other tests.)

Comment: `isupper('é')` (or some other character outside ASCII-7 range) may fail. Better be safer with a cast: `isupper((unsigned char)'é')`

Comment: @pmg Good point! I'm not sure, but can cases like accented letters be handled by locale settings?

Comment: @pmg Why would that be safer? The `isupper()` function takes an `int` as its argument and (in the C locale) returns true if that is one of the uppercase letters defined by the standard (which are the 26 uppercase letters of the latin alphabet). Therefore, it will just return false for anything else.

Comment: [C11 7.4p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4): "if [the argument is not representable as unsigned char] the behavior is undefined"

Comment: @pmg Wow, okay... point taken. I hate it when the standard doesn't have at least a small foot-note mentioning the undefined behavior (or the range of allowed values) in the actual chapter itself